# Add pac-item to google place autocomplete api

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

I need to add an additional "pac-item" to google places autocomplete API. This additional div will have a link to enter address manually. I need new pac-item at the end of the suggestions in the drop-down list.

Comment: Not sure you're going to get much help without providing some example code. Could you create an example and edit your question?

Comment: you can do it like this, tested and working: `setTimeout(function(){  $(".pac-container").append('<div id="areasearch" class="pac-item"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>qwerty</span> <span>Area</span></div>');
    }, 1000);`

Comment: @hberg He cannot create a code sample because the way google API works, the pac-items are elements auto-generated by google API.